# Does a character get all Skills or just Class Skills?

Tags: character-creation, skills, star-wars-saga-edition

### Introduction

A friend and I have recently decided to give Star Wars Saga Edition a go and before we introduce it to our entire group, we want to run a few short 1-on-1 adventures to get the hang of the system.

As we read through the Core Rulebook, we became confused about which skills are available to each character class.

### Questions

1. **Can a character use all skills (except the ones that explicitly require training) available in the game?** Or simply the ones listed under class skills in the class description?
2. If all skills are usable by any character, then **what are the differences between Class Skills and other skills?**
3. **What different ways of advancing a skill are available?** I am not asking for specific ways to advance specific skills, but rather general ways of improving skills.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1) Yes, a character can use any skill that doesn't explicitly require training to use.

2) Class Skills are skills that the character has available to train at 1st level. For example, the Jedi class has 2 + Int mod Trained Skills, and a Class Skill list that includes Acrobatics, Endurance, Initiative, Knowledge, Perception, Pilot, and Use the Force. So if the character had an Int score of 14, their Int mod would be 2, so they could choose any 4 of the skill on that list to have as trained.

3) You can gain training in a skill by taking the Skill Training feat, and you can get +5 to a specific trained skill with the Skill Focus feat. You can get Skill Focus multiple times, but you have to pick a different trained skill each time, so you can get Skill Focus(Pilot) and Skill Focus(Knowledge(Technology)) but not Skill Focus(Pilot) twice.

Comment: Errata added Jump and Mechanics to the Jedi's list of class skills.